# OAuth fails after deploying google glass application

Tags: python, google-glass

I went through the instructions on for the Google Glass Python Quick Start. I deployed the app and the app supposedly finished deploying successfully. I then went to the main URL for the app and attempted to open the page. The page asked me which Google Account I wanted to use to access the app, and I chose one. It went through some type of redirect and then came back to my app and tried to open up the openauth2callback page at which time nothing else happened. It just stopped on the openauth2callback page and sat there whitescreened.

I assume that the app is supposed to look like the sample app that was posted where I should see timeline cards and be able to send messages, but I don't see any of that.

I checked my oauth callbacks and they look exactly like the quick start instructions said to make them. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that are standard debugging practices, and you may want to update the original question to clarify:

1. Did OAuth actually fail? What information do you have that it failed? Can you verify from web server logs that the callback URL was hit and that it contained non-error return values?
2. Can you check your web server and app server logs to see if there are any error messages or exceptions logged?